# How to use panels for embeded nodes?

Tags: panels

I use [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to embed nodes within nodes.*

When editing these nodes, the embedded nodes appear as one block within Panels, so I cannot re-arrange the fields inside the embedded nodes:

[image: Current Situation]

I would like to split out the nodes into separate panes. I would also like to be able to re-arrange the fields in each embedded node using Panels drag-and-drop interface, as in this mock up:

[image: Mock up of desired space]

How can I achieve this?

Mini Panels lets you get the first child node only.
Views Context gets all the embedded nodes. However, it will lump similar fields together. (e.g. all the image fields will be displayed in one pane).

*(Embedding nodes within  nodes is useful as each separate node can hold a group of fields. The effect is similar to [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection), but there are extra advantages such as being able to share content between nodes).

Comment: I have found that you can use mini-panels to achieve part of what I want, but there are some draw backs: 1) Mini Panels don't work with the In Place Editor 2) In the mini panel, you have to create a separate relationship for each embedded node.  So if you have a lot of embedded nodes, that's a lot of relationships!

Comment: Quick clarification question: when you say "When editing these nodes", do you mean editing their display in the panels Content page, or do you mean on the Node edit form when editing the content of the parent node?

Comment: I mean editing the display with panels (i.e.e re-arranging the field positioning). Sorry, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: No problem, that's what I thought you probably meant, just checking

Comment: Looking at the question again, when you say "the fields in the 3 child nodes have been re-arranged", do you mean EVERY individual child node can be re-arranged by hand by the user, so each one could be different even though they are the same content type in the same list? If that's right, skip to my last comment about Panel nodes. It's not very clear what you mean, since in the image they all have the same layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just checking I've understood the problem correctly (please correct me if wrong):

- You have a page set up using panels,  on which you want to display a node and that node's child nodes.
- You want a list of child nodes that is configurable. Mini panels don't work well for as the number of child nodes can vary.
- Panels is essential, Inline Entity Form is not necessarily essential but is the best option you've found so far for giving nodes child nodes

---

If this is right, I wonder if you couldn't get what you want using Context [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) in  panels that use relationships from [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module (or [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) might do the job more simply - Inline Entity Form might work the same way too but I don't know how well it integrates with Views). After all, lists of any number of items from one relationship with configurable fields  is something Views is designed for, and using a context view allows you to chop the view up in Panels and place each part of the view in a way that suits your layout:

- Create a directional relation type between the appropriate node types - let's call it 'Is child of' (or, add  an entity reference field to  the parent node content type)
- Create a view block showing content and give it a Context display ( context displays are a display type along the top like Page, Block...)
- Give it a contextual filter for the Nid of the parent node, and a required relationship using the entity reference or relation to get the referred child node (if it doesn't work first time, the last time I used relation with views you had to chain node>relation and relation>node relationships to get the other node. Direct node>node relationships didn't work. Might be fixed by now)
- Add and configure your fields however you want them in Views, using the 'Is child of' relationship for each of them
- In Panels, load the view as context on the Panels Context page (make sure the view's contextual filter gets the nid somehow)
- In Panels Content page, you'll find the elements of your view under View Context. You can place all rows (each row being one child node), individual rows or row ranges, and header, footer, exposed filters etc whereever you like in your panels layout.

The individual fields within each 'embedded' child node are controlled in Views - which has all the flexibility of Panels  plus extra features for rewriting, tailoring and combining individual fields - and the display between  the child nodes and  each other and other page elements is controlled in Panels.

If you choose Relation, you can also add fields to the  linking relation itself, which can be included in each row of the view. I  believe you could also have one multiple endpoint relation where one parent has several children on the same relation entity sharing the same relation fields. Not sure if they've got those cases working with Views yet, though. Entity Reference is less powerful, but simpler.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but it seems you have to re-organize the fields with views, rather than panels. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @big_smile Not doing anything wrong at all - Views is ideal for organising fields in cases where there are *lists or multiples of things of the same type* (as here where there can be multiple child nodes): it's what it's optimised for and makes use of its features like sorting, pagination, filters, etc. Views also has finer control over the fields - for example, re-writing. The Panels family (Panels, mini-panels, cTools Page Manager...) are best for organising a variety of *singular things of different types*. It's really common to configure a list in Views, and then place the list in Panels.

Comment: This is why you're having trouble with mini-panels - it's designed for mixing things of different types, not for a number of things (child nodes) of the same type, so you end up needing lots of relationships. In views, you create the relationship once, and it's used once to get all the related content in one efficient query. It's what it's designed to do :)

Comment: And with the Context View, you can customise how the view is displayed using Panels - for example, you could have the first child node in one column with a class that highlights it, child nodes 2-4 (if there are that many) in a side column, a pager above and below this side column... or whatever works for your layout. If you need fields wholly seperate from each other, like in different Panels regions or columns, you could maybe split them between the main view and an Attachment View and place these seperately in Panels... not sure as I've never needed to do that.

Comment: I've been following your guidance. However, even when using views, all the content seems to be lumped together. For example, you can chose to display the body_text_field in a panel by using Views Context. But then all the body_text_field for all the child nodes are lumped together in a sample panel. Is there anyway to output these fields as separate panels? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @big_smile If you mean, you want child node 1 in one panel, child node 2 in another, etc etc, you can use the 'views row' limit and offset controls - so limit 1, offset 0 would be the first row only (first node), limit 1, offset 1 would be the second, etc. If you're trying to do something more complex it might help if you could sketch the layout you are aiming for, with say Panels regions as grey rectangles and each field name and row number labelled as a box with a black outline, and add that to the question.

Comment: Cool. So what in that design are you currently unable to do? You can separate each node (each row) using the limit/offset method above. To get the image to float to the right is just CSS: for more fine control, I would set every Views field to 'exclude from display', then add a Global: Custom Text field including the others with replacement patterns, something like `<div class="image float">[image]</div><div class="text">[title] [body]</div>` (check those [tokens] are right). This is a great Views feature and common good practice for super-fine control over how each field and row displays.

Comment: @big_smile also, if the goal is a simple straight list like this, and you want them in separate panels for styling purposes, you might not need to go to the trouble of separating them out into seperate panes as well, you might be able to add a class to each row in Views and simply use that. If there is a reason to panels (e.g. to put some rows in one column and other rows somewhere else) you can get that control from View context > View row etc.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while the Panels drag and drop thing is really handy, it's more of a way to try out layouts and ideas than a complete replacement to code everywhere all the time. See for example http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39486/can-panel-divs-be-removed Here, the layout of each child node is pretty straightforward - basically just `float: right;` and a left margin on the image element, then styling. Trying to force the panels interface in here seems a bit like overkill.

Comment: I know what I was doing wrong... In Views, under Format, select "Panel Fields". This gives the option to arrange fields in a Panels layout. You have to select "Panel fields" for each type of view (e.g. Master, Context etc) because it doesn't always carry over. Then when you add the View to Panels, click on "contexts" (in the left side bar) and then click on "relationships" and add " Node from view". Finally, go back to "content", select the "View row", Click on Visibility rules and select "Content exists"/" Node from view". This will ensure the view row is not printed when the row is empty.

Comment: The example posted above is only one type of layout. I have several mark-up friendly Layouts I have created. I want my users to be able to drag and drop the fields, as they are not technical and so cannot do CSS. Is there anyway of using the Drag and Drop interface of panels in Views (with the "Panel Fields")? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Ah!! "I want my users to be able to drag and drop the fields" - okay, this is the really important bit, that changes the question quite a lot! Does the panel fields option work for this? You should only need to set it in the Context view (unless you use the Master view separately elsewhere).

Comment: The "Panel Fields" option lets you customize the layout in Views using Drop Down box menus. It's a lot easier than CSS, but its not quite as easy as Drag and Drop editor in Panels. There doesn't seem to be anyway in Panels to to alter that Views layout. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: ...so how much customisation does each user need to be able to do? Your images seem to show a standard template for each row - but it sounds like you want users to be able customise their own layouts? If when you say users you mean a small number of disciplined people like staff or moderators, then something where they can create view modes could work (I won't duplicate what tmsimont's added about that), but if by users you mean anyone who signs up wikipedia-style, you're going to need to give a limited selection else you'll end up with confused users creating 100s of view modes.

Comment: @big_smile Either way it sounds like you've got enough to try things and see what works best. Exactly how much flexibility to give will depend on the exact needs, skill level and trust-ability of your users - and only you know that. I'd suspect that, unless your users are trusted Drupal site builders, you'll need to create a few layouts and let them switch (node-by-node, could have a drop down field that in Views switches CSS class), but again that's one for you to call. If they are site builders and they're editing content *types* as well as individual content, panel view modes are perfect.

Comment: ...and if what you want is to allow people to define the layout of *each individual node* with complete flexibility, that's more or less what the Panel content type is for (node/add/panel - make sure Panel Nodes panels sub module is enabled). They can give each node its own layout, then you include it in views using "Display full rendered node" instead of fields, and arrange the views rows from the context view in Panels. I think that's almost every possibility covered!!!

Comment: Only site builders will be editing the content and it is per a content type basis. It looks like the only way they can do this (for embedded nodes) is with the Panel Field option in Views. It's not as flexible as the Panels editor, but it is better than CSS. Thanks for your help! I have given you the bounty. I wish I could increase the bounty points as you have been really helpful, but it doesn't seem to let me do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using user568458's solution, but instead of displaying fields in the view, display a "fully rendered node" and set the view mode to a custom view mode.

To customize a view mode, and then configure the layout of a custom view mode, use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

See [this](http://zugec.com/blog/77-display-suite-part-2-view-modes-and-fields) about view modes.

If you activate Display Suite's sub module *Panel View modes*, [you can then use the Panels module interface](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lyBRbUR-hY), instead of Display Suite for layouts.

**EDIT**
I just went to do this myself and discovered that this feature has disappeared in the latest version of Display Suite!

Bummer :(

However, you can still utilize Display Suite to a lesser degree... Sorry

Comment: Nice video, +1. If the asker allows users to customise content *types*, and they want users to be able to create one custom layout for everything in each content type, this will work and fill in the last piece of the puzzle. I'm not clear whether they want the customisation to be for each page layout, each content type, or each individual node... Anyway between this tip, my comment about Panel nodes, and everything else, I think we've got an option for every single possibility!!! (p.s. Panel View Modes is in Display Suite not Panels - editted)

Comment: thanks for the edit -- i recently started using Display Suite view modes and I absolutely love it